# What preprocessor macro will resolve pinMode and digitalWrite?

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino

I am new to programming and need some help.

My goal is to make an LED blink using my SainSmart Arduino Nano. I found a sample program on Stack Overflow and it makes sense but I cannot seem to resolve all of the functions. I am using eclipse Mars.1 with CrossGCC on Windows 8.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int ledPin = 13;                 

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                  
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    
  delay(1000);                 
}
```

pinMode, digitalWrite, and delay will not resolve. I tried including arduino.h but that didn't solve it. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you specify in Eclipse that you are targetting arduino? Does the same file compile in Arduino standard development IDE?

Comment: Yes I did and Eclipse recognizes my arduino as a target. Currently I don't have that IDE but I will try it. I was under the impression that your compiler had more to do with this type of issue than your development environment.